# Dose @synthesize notation affect lazy instantiation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

We all know that the new objective c complier automatically performs the @synthesize to create property setter and getters. [As described here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html)

My question is how is the performance?

We know that if we write the getters ourselves. There are chances that we can implement lazy instantiation which is pretty good for the memory management.
But if we using the default @synthesize or not using the @synthesize at all, how much will be the difference regarding the performance?

For example

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *newArray;

//Approach 1:
@synthesize newArray = _newArray;

//Approach 2:
-(NSArray *)newArray {

  if(!_newArray){
    _newArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3"...@"1000",nil];
  }
  return _newArray;
}
```

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its unclear what exactly you are asking, hope this helps:

The performance difference between a basic self-written getter - one which just returns the value in the backing variable - and an automatically generated getter should be negligible at worst. There is so little for such a getter to do it is hard for anyone to it badly!

If you want to do lazy initialisation of a property the first time it is read then you must write the getter yourself, and if you need to be thread safe use `dispatch_once()` not a simple `if` test.

Comment: I realise now that the lazy instantiation is not related to the @synthesize notation. It depends on whether you put the initialisation logic in the initialiser or the getter of the property.